# Одинковый хешкод у мп3 файлов

Tags: java, apache, javafx

С помощью `String digest = DigestUtils.md5Hex(input);`
считываю хеш мп3 файла и записываю в listview `langs.add(data.getHashCode());`
снизу скрин где все хеши одинаковые

```
public  void readFiles(File baseDirectory) {


        try {

            Iterator<File> iterator = FileUtils.iterateFiles(baseDirectory, new String[]{"mp3"}, true);
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {


                File fileloop = iterator.next();


                InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
                Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                Mp3Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();

                parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);

                String digest = DigestUtils.md5Hex(input);

                input.close();

                String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
                Mp3data track = new Mp3data();

                track.setArtist(metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                track.setAlbum(metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                track.setTitle(metadata.get("title"));
                track.setDuration(toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration")));
                track.setPath(fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
                track.setHashCode(digest);

                mp3data.add(track);


            }
            Collections.sort(mp3data);
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

вот

```
public String getHashCode(){
        return hashcode;
    }


    public Mp3data setHashCode(String hashcode){
        this.hashcode = hashcode;
        return this;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это хеш пустого файла. Весь поток к этому времени уже прочитан `parser.parse`

Comment: спасибо, но если я выше пишу считывание хешсуммы то вылетает ошибка

Comment: все раозбрался просто добавил еще один поток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто нужно добавить еще один поток `InputStream input2 = new FileInputStream(fileloop);`

```
public  void readFiles(File baseDirectory) {


        try {

            Iterator<File> iterator = FileUtils.iterateFiles(baseDirectory, new String[]{"mp3"}, true);
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {


                File fileloop = iterator.next();


                InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                InputStream input2 = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
                Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                Mp3Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                String digest = DigestUtils.md5Hex(input2);
                parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);

                input.close();

                Mp3data track = new Mp3data();

                track.setArtist(metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                track.setAlbum(metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                track.setTitle(metadata.get("title"));
                track.setDuration(toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration")));
                track.setPath(fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
                track.setHashCode(digest);

                mp3data.add(track);


            }
            Collections.sort(mp3data);
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```